# keras Lambda "TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" and "TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument:"

Tags: lambda, keras, arguments, layer

I came across these issues when working with Lambda in Keras and it was not completely clear to me why it happens. Here is a solution to these issues. If there are any others out there I would be very interested.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

get_lambda = lambda a,b: tf.matmul(a,b)
get_lambda(tf.zeros((1,2)),tf.zeros((2,1)))
```

gives a correct solution:

```
<tf.Tensor 'MatMul_6:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>
```

However if I use this lambda inside of a Lambda layer I get an error:

```
get_lambda_layer = keras.layers.Lambda(get_lambda)
get_lambda_layer(tf.zeros((1,2)),tf.zeros((2,1)))

TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

So the Lambda layer expects 2 arguments as described https://keras.io/layers/core/ and the input must be one tensor or a list of tensors. So if I pass the inputs as a list to the Lambda layer like so, it should be fine for the layer:

```
get_lambda_layer( [ tf.zeros((1,2)),tf.zeros((2,1)) ] )

TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

It works for the layer but not for my initial lambda function which expects arguments:a,b so in this case my entire list of inputs will be considered a = [ tf.zeros((1,2)),tf.zeros((2,1)) ] while b has no value thus the error.

My solution is to create the lamda function with one argument as a list and use it like so:

```
get_lambda2 = lambda x: tf.matmul(x[0],x[1])
get_lambda_layer2 = keras.layers.Lambda(get_lambda2)
get_lambda_layer2([tf.zeros((1,2)),tf.zeros((2,1))])
```

Results in:

```
<tf.Tensor 'lambda_25/MatMul:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>
```

So this works since the argument (as a list) is passed from the Lambda layer to the lambda function.

There may be more elegant solutions out there and I am interested to know them.

Comment: Your solution is correct: the function invoked by a Lambda layer should expect a single argument with a tensor or a list of tensors. It is stated in the documentation.